# Updating to swift 4 broke Facebook verification in my app with ‘toUIntMax()’ obsoleted

Tags: swift, swift4

I get two different error's for the same thing, it says on the Buildtime Error's tab `"Swift Compiler Error"` and in the drop down for it, it says `'toUIntMax()' was obsoleted in Swift 4`. The next error says `'toUIntMax()' is unavailable`

This is all under a toolbox icon for FacebookCore, and I don't know enough to go in and start messing with something in here, because I would probably create even more problems. Reading where it's at it looks like it's part of a function that says it does `"Create an event that indicatest the user has rated an item in the app."` and it's all in the swift file called AooEvent.BuiltIn.swift

I've looked for a solution but can't find anything from Apple, or on here.

Comment: You can keep your third-party libraries in Swift 3.2 alongside your new Swift 4 code, you don't have to convert the libraries.

Comment: Is there a way to manually choose which swift version they're in? I didn't select to convert any of these libraries when I converted my project.

Comment: When Xcode suggests to convert to Swift 4, it shows you a list of modules. Uncheck the ones you don't want to convert, and also uncheck "Remind me later".

Answer (score 6):

> ‘toUIntMax()’ obsoleted

As per the [link](http://kristofk.com/facebook-swift-sdk-updated-to-swift-4/)

**Replace this:**

```
$0.toUIntMax() as UInt64
```

**With this:**

```
UInt64($0)
```

Comment: I have done this changes but i m getting "Cannot subscript a value of type 'String.UnicodeScalarView' with an index of type 'CountableRange<String.UnicodeScalarView.IndexDistance>" error  in AppInvite.PromoCode.swift file